# How to select only the 4 last list items?

Tags: jquery, listitem

I want to show only the last four list items.

Say i have this list:

```
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li
</ul>
```

And only want to show, Two, Three, Four and Five.
How can I do this with jQquery?

Comment: Why bother with jQuery when you can do this with CSS?

Comment: Support for older web browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it using JQuery. It is a generic code for any number of `li` that you have.
Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/SukanyaHalder/gfwjj8Lh/1/) fiddle.

```
li {
    display:none;
}
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   // alert();
    ShowHide();

    function ShowHide() {
       // alert($("ul"));
        $("ul").each(function () {

            if ($(this).children("li").length >= 4) {
                AddDisplay(4,$(this));

            } else AddDisplay($(this).children("li").length,$(this));
        });
    }

    function AddDisplay(num,obj) {
        if (num != null && num != undefined && num <= 4) {
            for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
               // alert(obj.children("li:eq(-" + i + ")").html());
                obj.children("li:eq(-" + i + ")").css("display", "block");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A simple CSS selector can do it.

You can simple use [`.nth-last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child) to select the 4 last items :

```
ul li{
    display : none;
}

ul li:nth-last-child(-1n+4){
    display : block;
}
```

If you have to support ie8 and lower, use jQuery :

```
$('ul li:nth-last-child(-1n+4)').show()
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the script i use to complete this task. 
HTML is

```
   <li>One</li>
   <li>Two</li>
   <li>Three</li>
   <li>Four</li>
   <li>Five</li>
  </ul>
```

here is the script

```
   $(function(){   
    $('ul li:nth-child(1)').hide();
  });
```

and this is how you can do with with css

```
ul li:nth-child(1){display:none;}
```

Regards

Comment: Thank you.

Will test it :)